# Match variadic template args to lambda parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I want to write a function that you call like so:

```
f("a", 1,                 [](float a                  ) { … });
f("a", 1, "b", 2,         [](float a, float b         ) { … });
f("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, [](float a, float b, float c) { … });
```

What the function does is immaterial. The point is that each pair of char*/integer parameters to `f` corresponds to a float parameter to the lambda function. I get as far as this:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void f(Args... args, std::function<void(???)> cb);
```

How can I declare the functor type so that the cardinality of its parameters matches the cardinality of the input pairs?

Comment: Do you need the template to be that specific so other overloads of `f` can be selected when the parameters aren't those types?  If yes, you need a SFINAE technique.  If no, I'd recommend making the template more general, and add a `static_assert` in the template definition to make it easier to debug incorrect calls.

Comment: Why not just use something like `template<typename... Args, typename T> void f(Args&&... args, T func)`?

Comment: @aschepler: The function will only be overloaded for pairs of `char*`/`int`. When you say "SFINAE" do you mean something like KennyTM's suggestion?

Comment: @KennyTM: I would like to be able to stipulate the functor's signature, but your suggestion will suffice. If you make it an answer, I'll probably accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requiring a function object argument, typically you should just allow the function to accept any type, and let the compiler emit the errors automatically when the type actually mismatch.

```
template <typename... Args, typename F>
void f(const F& func, Args&&... args) { ... }
```

(Note that I have moved the function argument to the front, because the variadic part will consume all arguments otherwise.)